# The data corresponding to the ManagementForm does not exist or has been modified

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I'm currently working with the nestedformset_factory bookstore for Django, because I have the following situation, I have a Restaurante model and a TipoCarta model (which would be how the possible sections of the menu), each restaurant, adds one or many Letters to its menu, which selects from the records available in the table TipoCarta. In addition, each letter can have from one to many products. (I attach the model of the domain of said situation)

Domain model

[image]

The problem that I have, is that I must show the user a form where I can register a restaurant and in it, I can add their respective letters and each letter, I can add their respective products, with their prices, but when I have to save in my database registered data, Django shows me the following error:

Error

[image]

But when I inspect the page and the data that was sent in the POST, everything seems normal:

POST

[image]

```
class RestauranteCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Restaurante
    template_name = 'calculadora/restaurante.html'
    form_class = RestauranteForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('calculadora:restaurantes')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RestauranteCreateView, self).get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['carta_formset'] = nestedformset_factory(
            Restaurante,
            Carta,
            form=CartaForm,
            min_num=1,
            max_num=5,
            extra=0,
            can_delete=False,
            nested_formset=inlineformset_factory(
                parent_model=Carta,
                model=Producto,
                form=ProductoForm,
                min_num=1,
                max_num=20,
                extra=1,
                can_delete=False
            )
        )
        return self.render_to_response(context)
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    restaurante_form = self.get_form(form_class)
    carta_formset = CartaFormSet(request.POST, prefix='carta')
    producto_formset = ProductoFormSet(request.POST, prefix='producto')
    if restaurante_form.is_valid() and carta_formset.is_valid() and producto_formset.is_valid():
        restaurante = Restaurante.objects.update_or_create(
            nombre=restaurante_form['nombre'].value(),
            direccion=restaurante_form['direccion'].value(),
            telefono=restaurante_form['telefono'].value(),
            mapa=restaurante_form['mapa'].value(),
            administrador=request.user,
            barrio=restaurante_form['localidad'].value()
        )
        for carta_form in carta_formset:
            carta = Carta.objects.update_or_create(
                tipo=carta_form['tipo'],
                restaurante=int(restaurante)
            )
            carta.save()
            for producto_form in producto_formset:
                producto = Producto.objects.update_or_create(
                    carta=carta,
                    nombre=producto_form['nombre'],
                    precio_fijo=producto_form['precio_fijo']
                )
                producto.save()
        context = {
            'messages': ['El restaurante ha sido registrado exitosamente.']
        }
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url, context=context)
```

Form

[image]

restaurante_carta_add.html

```
<div class="row" id="carta-management-form">
    {{ carta_formset.management_form }}
</div>
{% load bootstrap %}
{% for carta_form in carta_formset %}
    <div id="{{ carta_form.prefix }}-row" class="row {{ carta_formset.prefix }}">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">
                            <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fw"></i>
                            Sección
                            <a class="pull-right" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{ carta_form.prefix }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{ carta_form.prefix }}" title="Añade productos a esta sección">
                                Productos <i class="fa fa-plus fw"></i>
                            </a>
                            {% if forloop.last %}
                                <!--
                                    <span id="add-{{ carta_form.prefix }}-btn" type="button"  class="pull-right" onclick="cloneMore('{{ carta_form.prefix }}', '{{ carta_formset.prefix }}', false)">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus fw"></i>
                                    </span>
                                -->
                            {% else %}
                                <!--
                                    <span id="remove-{{ carta_form.prefix }}-btn" type="button"  class="pull-right" onclick="deleteForm('{{ carta_form.prefix }}', '{{ carta_formset.prefix }}')">
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-alt fw"></i>
                                    </span>
                                -->
                            {% endif %}
                        </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            {{ carta_form|bootstrap_horizontal }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="{{ carta_form.prefix }}" class="row collapse">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <legend>
                                Productos de la sección
                            </legend>
                            {% include 'calculadora/restaurante_producto_add.html' %}                                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

restaurante_producto_add.html

```
<div>
    <div class="row" id="producto-management-form">
        {{ carta_form.nested.management_form }}
    </div>
    <div  class="row">
        {% load bootstrap %}
        {% for producto_form in carta_form.nested %}
            <div id="{{ producto_form.prefix }}-row" class="row {{ carta_form.nested.prefix }}">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2 col-lg-2 ">Producto</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-10">
                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <div>
                                    {{ producto_form.nombre }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group-addon">
                                    /
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    {{ producto_form.precio_fijo }}
                                </div>
                                {% if forloop.last %}
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span id="add-{{ producto_form.prefix }}-btn" type="button" onclick="cloneMore('{{ producto_form.prefix }}', '{{ carta_form.nested.prefix }}')">
                                            <i class="fa fa-plus fw"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span id="remove-{{ producto_form.prefix }}-btn" type="button" onclick="deleteForm('{{ producto_form.prefix }}', '{{ carta_form.nested.prefix }}')">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-alt fw"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me, because I've been with this problem for several days and I have not been able to solve it, I asked Stackoverflow in Spanish and nobody helped me, so I went here, I tried to use the Jquery dynamic FormSet library, but this one it would be useful if only it were sending a formset, but in my case, I send 2 formsets and a form, in which, the first formset depends on the form and each formset, another formset depends. I insist when I tell them that I have tried everything I found in Stackoverflow and nothing works for me, I even put a prefix to each formset and keep throwing that error. Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: add the codes in `def post` as I think there is some problems in the post method

Comment: I have implemented the post method, maybe the implementation is wrong

Comment: Let us see the implementation

Comment: I just published the method

Comment: please show the template.  where did you include `{{ form.management_form }}`?

Comment: Of course, at this moment I show you the templates. I have added the management_form for both formsets

Comment: @HenryM Could you check the templates?

Comment: I assume you have a `<form>` tag around the formsets.  Could you show `CartaFormSet` and `ProductoFormSet`.  If not, please work through a couple of tutorials so you can see the basic approach

Comment: Thanks @HenryM, I managed to solve it by implementing the nested form in a different way, without making use of the free nested_formset